# How to use pagination in a search form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a searching system with pagination in Laravel that displays the results refined by multiple options from an inquiry list.

The refined search works fine, but when I click the pagination link, the all options are reset.

First, I was trying to store sessions but it didn't work somehow.

After I posted this question, I changed my code as below.
Currently, I'm trying to use "attends" but still it doesn't work.
The options are reset when I click the pagination link.

** Codes below are edited after posted this question. **

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Contact;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $contacts = Contact::paginate(10);
        return view('admin/index', ['contacts' => $contacts]);
    }

    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $query = Contact::query();

        $fullname = $request->input('fullname');
        $gender = $request->input('gender');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $created_at_start = $request->input('created_at_start');
        $created_at_end = $request->input('created_at_end');

        if ($fullname != '') {
            $query->where('fullname', 'like', '%'.$fullname.'%');
        }
        /* Other IF options */
        else {
            $contacts = Contact::paginate(10);
        }

        $contacts = $query->paginate(10);

        return view('admin/index', compact('contacts'));
    }
}
```

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ContactController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
Route::get('admin', [ContactController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('admin.search', [ContactController::class, 'search'])->name('admin.search');
```

SearchForm:

```
<form class="search-box__items" action="admin" method="GET">
      @csrf
        <label class="search-box__items__label">
          Name
          <input name="fullname" type="text" class="search-box__item" value="{{ $fullname ?? '' }}">
        </label>
        <!-- Other options -->
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<div class="contacts">
    <div class="pagination">
      {{ $contacts->appends(['fullname'=>$fullname ?? ''])->links() }}
    </div>
    <div class="contacts-table">
      <!-- Inquiry list -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I mentioned that there are no logs in storage/framework/sessions but it was a mistake. I found a log after I posted this question. But not in the Session Storage of Chrome dev tool.

Comment: Can you show the search form

Comment: Its not necessary to store it in Session you can just add as url parameter

Comment: I tried this code but it still doesn't work. {{ $contacts->appends(['fullname'=>$fullname ?? ''])->links() }}

Comment: please check the data if coming ( from the request ) on post, if it comes, then check if it stores on the session. ( i guess the trouble there ), also you can reduce your code using :- 
$data = $request->only('...prameters'); 
$request->session()->put('params',$data); also you can use same index method while "POST", you will not need redirect.

Comment: @Debasis Rath
 Data is coming but it not stores on the session.

Comment: when you use ```{{ $contacts->appends(['fullname'=>$fullname ?? ''])->links() }}``` you must use ```GET``` method in form tag

Comment: I use the code as I edited in my question. And changed the method from POST to GET.

Comment: When I click the pagination link, the url is 'http://localhost:8000/admin.search?fullname=&page=2'. It looks like the 'fullname' value is deleted when the pagination link is clicked.

Comment: It's solved. I just made a mistake in the variable returned from the controller, and there was no problem about the pagination. The pagination works fine and doesn't reset the options when the link is clicked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The link needs to keep the search term in the URL as well, as the form is not submitted when you click the page navigation.